# Source of randomness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, randomness

Is the random nature of all macroscopic phenomena like for example, turbulence or chemical kinetics ultimately traceable to quantum randomness?

Answer (score 3):

You are effectively asking *"What is the relationship between quantum mechanics and classical chaos?"* This is an open question and an intense area of study, known as [quantum chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chaos). Stack exchange questions on quantum chaos have already been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651011/is-there-quantum-randomness-that-significantly-affects-our-macro-world) (in a general context), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212946/is-long-term-weather-forecast-impossible-in-principle) (in the context of predicting the weather), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168831/can-quantum-fluctuations-affect-the-double-pendulum?rq=1) (in the context of the double pendulum), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658544/is-there-a-relationship-between-quantum-physics-and-chaos-theory-on-a-classical) (in the context of predicting the brain).

But in short, I'd answer your question like this:

If quantum mechanics was completely deterministic, chaotic macroscopic phenomena would still appear unpredictable to us, just because we will never know the initial conditions perfectly, and chaos exponentially amplifies uncertainty. But if you ask whether quantum mechanics makes most chaotic systems **fundamentally** unpredictable, then I'd say yes. Chaos can be one of many mechanisms by which quantum uncertainties / fluctuations have very macroscopic consequences.

However the precise understanding of classical chaos from a quantum mechanical perspective is difficult, because the Schrodinger equation is entirely linear, and so at first glance does not seem to be able to produce chaos. A subtler treatment involving many-body interactions is needed, and is being actively researched.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that chaos in classical phenomena does arise from fundamental randomness at the quantum level?

Comment: @Ajit Not really. Plain Newtonian mechanics has no shortage of chaotic systems, where outcomes are completely unpredictable for all practical intents and purposes. In fact, chaotic systems are much easier to find in Newtonian mechanics than in quantum mechanics, because QM is linear. Of course, if QM is the only source of fundamental randomness in the universe (which is the case in the Copenhagen interpretation of QM, but not in many worlds or Bohmian QM), then all fundamental randomness (not due to our ignorance) in classical chaotic systems is due to QM.

Comment: Deterministic chaos  is chaotic because of our inability to determine initial conditions to infinite precision. That is a mathematical result.  But from physics, precision is limited fundamentally by QM.  What is the more significant effect in actual macroscopic random phenomena?  In other words, does quantum randomness get averaged out, before deterministic chaos takes over?

Comment: @Ajit For practical macroscopic purposes, I'd say our uncertainty is much more important. But still, I don't think you can expect chaotic systems to somehow average out quantum randomness, when they amplify all other randomness. Especially when, for example, the width of a free particle's wavefunction spreads out continually over time.

Comment: @Ajit How you think about this may or may not depend on your preferred resolution to the problem of measurement / wavefunction collapse. In dynamical collapse theories, the wavefunction may be continually collapsing before reaching any macroscopic scales. In many worlds on the other hand, the wavefunction never collapses, so naturally becomes macroscopic, and different outcomes of chaotic macroscopic systems may happen in different worlds.

Comment: I agree.  Turbulence in a fluid results from chaotic solutions of deterministic mechanics. If so, there is a 'mesoscale', where random quantum fluctuations average out, before the scale at which chaos starts. Perhaps this is amenable to experimental verification.

Comment: In the case of chemical reactions, we see the averaged result of quantum fluctuations, as macroscopic kinetics. Chaotic behaviour in seen only some pathological cases.

Comment: Come to think of it. Turbulence regime limits are defined by a Reynold's number, ie., proportional to density. To get quantum fluctuations, we have to take a fluid containing only a few molecules, ie.,  the density is very small. As the density becomes low, Re becomes small and we would lose turbulence.

Answer (score 0):

No.Quantum randomness comes from the collapse of the wavefunction while the classical statistical randomness  is just our lack of ability to contruct measuring devices which dont change the states of the particles.

Comment: I think you are getting quantum and classical confused here:
*"in classical statistical randomness the states of the particles is just our lack of ability to construct measuring devices which don't change the states of the particles"*

Quantum mechanics has this restriction through the uncertainty principle. Classical mechanics doesn't. Uncertainty in classical mechanics comes from our ignorance of the initial conditions.